# Alert message for different dropdown choices

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a dropdown menu with options that bring up a different alert message for each option.

For example, a dropdown menu was created with the options "Algebra" "Chemistry" and "English 3".  I want an alert "Geometry course required" to pop up for Algebra.  "Biology course required" for Chemistry, and "English 1 and 2 courses required for English.

How do I do this?  Thanks!  I pretty much just need help with the function.

```
 <select id="test-dropdown" onchange="choice1(this)">
    <option value="1">Algebra</option>
    <option value="2">Chemistry</option>
    <option value="3">English 3</option>
 </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example - I am not using alert but instead change a text on the page
I also moved the event handler definition to the script instead of inline

Note I also added a "Please select" since you cannot show the text for Algebra if it is already selected when loading

```js
var choices = ["","Geometry course required","Biology course required","English 1 and 2 courses required"];
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById("test-dropdown").onchange=function() {
    document.getElementById("choice").innerHTML=choices[this.value];
  }
  document.getElementById("test-dropdown").onchange(); // show default
}
```

```html
     <select id="test-dropdown">
        <option value="0">Please select</option>
        <option value="1">Algebra</option>
        <option value="2">Chemistry</option>
        <option value="3">English 3</option>
     </select>
     <span id="choice"></span>
```

Without the Please select

```js
var choices = ["","Geometry course required","Biology course required","English 1 and 2 courses required"];
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById("test-dropdown").onchange=function() {
    document.getElementById("choice").innerHTML=choices[this.value];
  }
  document.getElementById("test-dropdown").onchange(); // show default
}
```

```html
     <select id="test-dropdown">
        <option value="1">Algebra</option>
        <option value="2">Chemistry</option>
        <option value="3">English 3</option>
     </select>
     <span id="choice"></span>
```

With alert

```js
var choices = ["","Geometry course required","Biology course required","English 1 and 2 courses required"];
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById("test-dropdown").onchange=function() {
    if (this.value !== 0) alert(choices[this.value]);
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="test-dropdown">
        <option value="0">Please select</option>
        <option value="1">Algebra</option>
        <option value="2">Chemistry</option>
        <option value="3">English 3</option>
     </select>
     <span id="choice"></span>
```

Comment: Thank you for that.  But I am trying to have different messages pop up, not just the name of the class.  For example, like I said originally, I want something like "Geometry course required" when Algebra is clicked on.  At the same time, I want something like "Biology course required" when Chemistry is clicked on.

Comment: Please see update and use your imagination. I did not initially feel like copying all that text into the variables. I now just replaced the text to show with the complete text

Comment: I show two versions - one with please select and added an onchange to show the text of the default

Comment: I appreciate the help and patience.  Sorry about that.  I could end up using that.  Is there a way to do this with alerts though?  I feel like that would be much more clean for the website.

Comment: Alerts are never cleaner. But yes, I have added an alert version

Comment: Thank you for the help.  I will run both versions and see what I like better.  Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```js
var a = document.getElementById('test-dropdown');
a.addEventListener('change',function(){
var b = document.querySelectorAll('option:checked');
for(var i = 0; i < b.length; i++){
if(b[i].value == 1){
alert('Geometry course required')
}else if(b[i].value == 2 ){
alert('Biology course required')
}else{
alert('English 1 and 2 courses required for English')
}
}
});
```

```html
<select id="test-dropdown">
    <option value="0">select option</option>
    <option value="1">Algebra</option>
    <option value="2">Chemistry</option>
    <option value="3">English 3</option>
 </select>
```

Answer (score -1):

Check this also in the [codepen] (https://codepen.io/scodek/pen/EboEQp),

```
function choice1(selected)
    {
        if(selected.options[selected.selectedIndex].text === "Algebra")
        {
          alert("Geometry course required");
        }
        else if(selected.options[selected.selectedIndex].text === "Chemistry")
        {
        alert("Biology course required");
        }
        else if(selected.options[selected.selectedIndex].text === "English 3")
        {
        alert("English 1 and 2 courses required for English");
        }
    }
```

Comment: That is horribly inefficient. DRY - Don't Repeat Yourself. Use the value or text as key in a lookup table. Also you do not use `element` in your pen

Comment: I will appreciate if you please clarify  as this is working fine in the codepen I attached.

Comment: 1. You access the text in every if/else. 2. You alert in every if/else 3. you get the dropdown in the function but used the passed dropdown so that line can go too

Comment: Thank you for your clarification. I specially did it this way as the question was to generate different alert message based on different text value of the options.

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gXoeEr - and the list of texts can even go outside the function